# WM 11.3.0.0 CompilerDriver[] fails to compile a C code with VS 2017 Community

Tags: compile, windows, c++

I am new at using CCompilerDriver[]. I call the C compiler from W Mathematica using recent WM 11.3 update. It  successfully identifies the Visual Studio 2017,  But calling compiler returns errors.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]
hello = CreateExecutable["
  #include <stdio.h>
  int main(){
    printf(\"hello world\\n\");
  }
  ", "hello"]
Import["!" <> QuoteFile[hello], "Text"]
```

I copy the sample test code from the WM documentation CCompilerDriver/ref/CreateExecutable

The output shows to recognize VS2017 , but fails to compile due to files missing. Please help with how to tell WM to find the missing files.

> Out[2]= {{"Name" -> "Visual Studio",    "Compiler" ->
>   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler,
>   "CompilerInstallation" ->     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual \ Studio\2017\Community",    "CompilerName" -> Automatic},
>   {"Name" -> "Visual Studio",    "Compiler" ->
>   CCompilerDriver`VisualStudioCompiler`VisualStudioCompiler,
>   "CompilerInstallation" ->     "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual \ Studio\2017\BuildTools", "CompilerName" -> Automatic}}
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= CreateExecutable::cmperr: Compile error:
>   C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Mathematica\SystemFiles\LibraryResources\Windows-x86-64\Working-asus-8568-6984-1\hello.c(2):
>   fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file
>   or directory
>
> Out[3]= $Failed
> > 
> > During evaluation of In[1]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at
> > position 2 in !<>QuoteFile[$Failed].
>
> During evaluation of In[1]:= Import::chtype: First argument
>   !<>QuoteFile[$Failed] is not a valid file, directory, or URL
> > specification.
> > 
> > Out[4]= $Failed

Additional information about my machine

version 11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows64-bit March 7, 2o18
Release ID 11.3.0.0

I have installed both compilers, the  Visual Studio IDE and the Visual Studio Built Tools

**1 st UPDATE:::**

I forgot to mention that I am also beginner to C++ .  I compiled the code above in VS2017 IDE and returned  errors. It looks the samples from the WM Documentation do not necessarily compile in the C++ compiler.

Have this said, I replaced the code with a sample code that showed to compile in VS2017 IDE. The result appears to have compiled in WM, but can not the Import line returned error. I can not associate this error to the compilation is related at all. Please , comment.

```
Needs["CCompilerDriver`"]
CCompilers[]

hello = CreateExecutable["

    // Hello100.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console \
application.
    //

    #include " stdafx.h "
    #include <iostream>
    // i/o example
    // stringstreams

    #include <string>
    #include <sstream>
    using namespace std;

    int main()
    {
        string mystr;
        float price = 0;
        int quantity = 0;
        int next;
        cout << " Enter price : ";
        getline(cin, mystr);
        stringstream(mystr) >> price;
        cout << " Enter quantity : ";
        getline(cin, mystr);
        stringstream(mystr) >> quantity;
        cout << " Total price : " << price * quantity << endl;
        cin >> next;
        return 0;
       }

         ", "hellomyfirst"];

Import["!" <> QuoteFile[hellomyfirst], Text]
```

The output :

> In[36]:= Import["!" <> QuoteFile[hellomyfirst], Text]
>
> During evaluation of In[36]:= StringJoin::string: String expected at
>   position 2 in !<>QuoteFile[hellomyfirst].
>
> During evaluation of In[36]:= Import::chtype: First argument
>   !<>QuoteFile[hellomyfirst] is not a valid file, directory, or URL
>   specification.
>
> Out[36]= $Failed

**2 st UPDATE:::**

Found the issue.. It is correct all the comments shared by contributors. Need the C++ SDK .. but must important is that in addition must have  Windows 10 In my case, my laptop was using Windows 8.1.

Comment: What goes in `Import` should be the path to the compiled executable.

Comment: Also it is questionable that the compilation succeeded, because there are unescaped quotes and backslashes in the source string.

Comment: The remaining question has been [cross-posted](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1330326) and answered on Wolfram Community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm. You can look up the location of `stdio.h` on your system and add that  manually to the `IncludeDirectories` for `CreateExecutable` like this (example path is the path on my macos system and will differ from what you need):

```
includepath = "/usr/include/c++/4.2.1";
SetOptions[
 CreateExecutable,
 "IncludeDirectories" -> 
  Append["IncludeDirectories" /. 
    Options[CreateExecutable, "IncludeDirectories"], 
    includepath
   ]
 ]
```

Still, something is fishy about the fact that Mathematica does not find it on its own. Did you install Mathematica before VisualStudio?

Comment: Schumacker   Yes.. I did. including all the several updates .

Comment: I am not sure, but if you installed Mathematica _before_ the compilers, then maybe Mathematica did not find all relevant paths. I don't know how to let Mathematica search after installation. So, reinstalling Mathematica _might_ resolve this problem. But that is only a guess... (like switching the computer off and on again ;)  )

Answer (score 2):

When installing Visual Studio 2017, make sure that the "Universal CRT SDK" component is selected (see the last checkbox), which should provide the relevant header files.

[image]

(Since there appear to be multiple issues involved, this is more of a comment than an answer, and is only intended for the problem in the original version of the question: compilation failing due to a missing system header file.)

Comment: I had all these except for WIndows 8.1 SDK. But still same problem.

Comment: The point is that UCRT SDK must be installed in order to have headers like stdio.h or stddef.h.